# Spivak chapter 22 Problem 27

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have came across problem 27(a), I couldn't seem to solve it. The question goes: Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence which is bounded, and let $y_n = \sup\{x_n, x_{n+1}, \cdots \}$. Prove that $\{y_n\}$ converges. The answer book says clearly $\{y_n\}$ is decreasing.

Here comes my question. What if $\{x_n\}$ is bounded above, doesn't that mean

$$y_1 = y_2 = \cdots = y_n = \cdots$$

so $\{y_n\}$ can be not decreasing?

Comment: Consider $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$. Then $y_n = \sup\{x_n, x_{n+1}, \cdots\} = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: What if I let $x_1=$x_2=....... =l So {$y_n} is not decreasing,right?

Comment: It would have been better to say that the sequence $y_n$ is nonincreasing, yes. But the statement in your second paragraph is still wrong, as Sangchul's nice example shows.

Comment: I am pretty sure that 'decreasing' in Spivak refers to the same thing as non-increasing, in the sense that $y_1 \geq y_2 \geq \cdots$.

Comment: Thanks a lot,guys!

Comment: @JohnHughes what if $x_n is a non decreasing sequence which limit is l? Sangchul's example is when $x_n is decreasing.

Comment: OK; look at $x_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$. How do you know that $y_5 \ge y_6$, directly from the definition?

Comment: Hint: suppose that $P \subset Q$, and both are finite. Can the maximum element of $P$ be larger than the maximum element of $Q$? OK, now generalize to the infinite case and suprema.

Comment: @JohnHughes Thanks a lot. So, $y_i is bigger or equal to $y_j for i smaller than j Since $y_i has all the elements belong to $y_j and some more.

Comment: Sorry for my horrible typesetting!

Comment: Well, $y_i$ and $y_j$ are numbers, so they don't have any elements. But the sets for which they are the suprema have the relationship you said, yes.

Comment: @JohnHughes thanks again. Will try to write things more carefully.